# PhpStorm - Full view on single file

Tags: netbeans, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I just started to use PhpStorm and wonder how I can enter full view for a single file?

In NetBeans I could just double click on the file:

[image: before double click]

...then the full view for that file was shown:

[image: after double click]

After double clicking on the file again, the normal view is shown again.

[image]

Is this also possible in JetBrains PhpStorm?

Answer (score 3):

This is not currently possible.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-82829 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

*(P.S. This [IDEA-166351](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-166351) looks the same .. so may be marked as duplicate of the first ticket at some point).*

---

To be clear: hiding all tool windows is easy (double click on editor tab or `Window | Active Tool Window | Hide All Windows` -- <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + F12</kbd> using Default keymap) -- it's "Maximize current editor tab and hide all other tabs" what is missing (absent feature).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, also on JetBrains IDEs (PhpStorm, WebStorm, etc.) is possible to double click on an editor tab to hide the rest of toolbars and sections and get a full clear view of the editor; then if you double click again on the editor tab, you can return to your previous IDE disposition.

Also you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> combination to hide/show all tool windows. (see here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.3/manipulating-the-tool-windows.html#d883741e144)

Comment: How does it work, I just tried it and the only thing that happens is that my navigation menu at the left disappears.

Comment: I edited the answer, adding a key combination to hide all tool windows, could you try this?

Comment: Does now work, maybe because I changed my keymap to netbeans?

Comment: Maybe the key combination is different for netbeans keymapping... However, I've tried that four files splitted view you show in the pictures on PhpStorm, and you're right that only the toolbars are closed when I dobule click an editor tab, but the four files split editor still there (not one file full view). I think that PhpStorm behaves different that NetBeans on editor splits; the first one only use one editor view where you can add splits, but the second one opens a new editor view for each split, so that's why you can have a full view of a split on NetBeans and not on PhpStorm.